# Define a function that calculates a sum

Tags: arrays, function, numpy, sum

My class is working with numpy, and we have an assignment where we're supposed to create a function that calculates a sum.

[image: Assignment Description]

I am trying to define the function C_series(x, k) that calculates the sum:

```
C(x; k) = the sum of (-1)^n*x^(2n) /(2n!) when n goes from 0 to k.
```

I'm having trouble here, and I've been able to find very little help by googling. I'm not even able to define the function correctly. I'm thinking I might need to put a for-loop in here somewhere since I want to iterate through the sum for the different x and k-values, but I'm not quite sure how to write this in code. This is what I have so far, but I'm pretty sure everything is wrong:

```
import numpy as np
def C_series(x, k):    
     return np.sum((-1)**n*x**(2*n))/np.math.factorial(2*n)

x = np.linspace(-3*pi, 3*pi, 7)
k = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you think that you might need a for-loop, why haven't you used one?

Comment: As I said, I wouldn't know where to put it. I'm still very new to programming, and this is the hardest assignment we've gotten until now. That is why I'm asking here for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 methods. One straight and one using the Horner scheme (slightly modified). Since your question is an assignment I'll leave figuring out how they actually work as an exercise.

```
def C(x, k, Horner=False):
    if Horner:
        res = -1 if k % 2 else 1
        for j in range(k, 0, -1):
            res *= x*x/(2*j*(2*j-1))
            res += 1 if j % 2 else -1
        return res
    else:
        terms = (x / np.arange(1, 2*k+1)).cumprod()[1::2]
        return 1 + terms[1::2].sum() - terms[::2].sum()
```